# Replacing comma with a period on numpad

Tags: keyboard-layout, xkb

I would like to achieve a certain effect. After pressing scroll lock its LED lights up and the comma on Numpad has been swapped with a period. I had modified the command given as the answer  [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/209636/how-to-change-decimal-comma-to-decimal-period-in-numpad).
The command I have come up with is as follows: `setxkbmap -option '' -option kpdl:dot -option grp:switch,grp:sclk_toggle,grp_led:scroll gb,pl`. However, it is not the best solution to my problem, since now the British keyboard layout is the default one. Additionally when pressing *alt* scroll lock LED lights up. Is there a way to achieve the opposite i.e. by pressing scroll lock Polish keyboard layout is swapped with British layout.

Comment: So, (1) what you really want is to have a comma on the keypad **only on pl**, right? ..... (2) Do you really need two languages? (3) Which ones? English and Polish? (4) do you want a comma or a dot on the English (GB) language layout?

Comment: (1) Yes, that's right. (2) Not necessarily. I just found a solution which uses two languages. (3) English and Polish (4) I want a dot on the English layout